# Difference between Actual Time and Base Time in react profiller api

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am learning how to use React profiler api and came accross tow parameters "Actual Time" and "Base Time". According to documentation

```
actualDuration: number - Time spent rendering the Profiler and its descendants for the current update. This indicates how well the subtree makes use of memoization (e.g. React.memo, useMemo, shouldComponentUpdate). Ideally this value should decrease significantly after the initial mount as many of the descendants will only need to re-render if their specific props change.

baseDuration: number - Duration of the most recent render time for each individual component within the Profiler tree. This value estimates a worst-case cost of rendering (e.g. the initial mount or a tree with no memorization).
```

But I am not able to understand these term.\

According to me what it means is actual time is total time component and it's children take to rerender and baseTime is total time component and it's children take if we don't use shouldComponentUpdate.

If I am wrong kindly clarify me I have saws some articles on medium.com but still confused

Answer (score 0):

**Actual time** is the actual time spent for rendering the committed update for the component. This value will be indicative of how well the component is making use of memoization and avoiding unnecessary re-renders etc. as it should reduce after initial mount if most of the child components are not changing and using memoization effectively.

**Base Time** provides the base estimated and required time to render the entire subtree of the component without memoization and gives the worst-case value for reference.

[Source](https://reactjs.org/docs/profiler.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it seems you are correct.

As far as I understand:

actualDuration: This is the actual measured time that your component took to render, including all optimizations you are using such as memo, shouldComponentUpdate, useMemo etc.

baseDuration: The baseDuration is the amount of time it took to render your component with perf improvements removed (such as memo, shouldCompUpdate etc). This value seems to be provided to see how much time you are saving using memoization.